# differentiate admin and user of android apps

Tags: android

i cant get the idea of it..
How to differentiate admin and user of the android apps if the apps do not provide the login function?
 how the admin manage the database of the apps?

Comment: Why don't you implement login method?

Comment: because it just a apps which provides information and let user to search... do not have other methods to let admin manage the database?

Comment: inside phone or sd card.it is an offline apps..

Comment: I`m sorry, i don`t understand, you build app whit integrated db in device and you want nobody can change the db except you?

Comment: Is that mean that if implement login method, the admin are able to manage the database although the database is in the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you need to store the db somewhere on server if you want to make changes on it, then you need to connect your app whit this db. If you have db only in-said the app/device only the user can make changes and you must give him the privileged to do that if you want.

Comment: increase your reputation score by accept this answer, otherwise your accepted rating will be low and you will not take answers.